# How can I get data from a websocket url?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, node.js, websocket

When I connect to a website who uses websockets, I can get the frames with the Google Developer Tools.

[Data from the websocket url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUkSK.gif)

So I would like to get the same data but in a program ( JS, C# ) but I actually have no idea how I should do.

I thought about make a http.request with NodeJS but it's not a http url :/
I thought about make a sample JS client but I couldn't get the data because I wasn't able to send the headers with the 'key'.

[The headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlDjG.png)

So, I really hope you have a way to help me and sorry for my basic English :(

Comment: You can use libraries like http://socket.io/ to connect with the ws:// and wss:// protocols.

Comment: A quick google came up with https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket for node. and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket(v=vs.110).aspx for .net

Comment: How do we get the websocket data from chrome dev tool into an external file ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WebSockets is a standard technology to implement stateful, persistent connections between clients and servers. It has its own protocol `ws://` and `wss://` (like `https://`).

What you need is a proper WebSocket client to receive data from the server.

The problem here is WebSockets it's not a protocol per se. There's no concept of request and response. It's like working with TCP sockets.

If you want to work with WebSockets, NodeJS has [Socket.IO client API](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/).

In C#, you should take a look at [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr).

Comment: I think I understood but one question persist: Must I set a headers ?

Comment: @Rynelf No you shouldn't have to set any specific headers if you are using socket.io. Follow the documentation, and you will be surprised how quickly you have something up and running.

Comment: @Rynelf As I said in my answer, a Websocket has no protocol. There're no headers, request body... it's like working with a raw network channel

Comment: I have a similar task. I need to access data from a websocket that runs in the chrome browser? Is this the way to go?

Comment: @Dr.YounesHenni Why not, BTW who knows the details of your case. I would post a new Q&A..